# How to scroll down on a frame(seperated by div) of webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, automation

I'm automating some manual work of finding a list of elements matching to the given string. The whole webpage doesn't have a scrollbar but only the left pane where operations are done has a scroll bar. Have tried using javascript executor, but couldn't scroll that particular element.

**I've tried:**

```
js.executeScript("driver.findElement(By.xpath(\"//div[@class='jss215 jss213 ']\")).scrollIntoView()");
```

**also tried by sending page_down keys**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jss215 jss213 ']")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

I get `ElementClickInterceptedException` and I'm trying to handle it by scrolling down till I get my element.

Comment: show html code of element you trying to operate on

Comment: <div class="jss215 jss213 " style="margin: -2px;"><div style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 2px;"><div tabindex="0" class="jss62 jss216 jss219 jss223 jss224" role="button" id="tree-PRODUCT" style="padding-left: 0px;"><div class="jss226 jss211" id="text"><div id="styled-text" style="font-weight: normal;"><span> <span>PRODUCT</span></span></div></div><span class="jss232"></span></div>

Comment: Rest of the html is about the list of elements in the tree. The element/ scroll view only has a div --> <div class="jss215 jss213 " style="margin: -2px;"><div style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 2px;">

Comment: have you tried solution provided below?

Answer (score 0):

For scroll to a element please try this bellow code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jss215 jss213 ']");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Tried it . But not working. :(

Comment: can you provide the link of webpage?

Comment: @SusmithaChannapragada please provide url webpage like above suggest

Comment: Hi @Frian it's our company's internal website. You wont be able to open it untill you're in our network. But it looks exactly like the image in https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjQHD.jpg but with div.